# How to enter data for authentication required pop up using ruby, page-object and watir-webdriver

Tags: ruby, authentication, watir, required

I feel my problem has a simple solution (although I am not able to find a relevant answer through researching). I am using RubyMine ruby 2.0.0 for automated testing and mostly using watir-webdriver, 0.6.4, and page-object, 0.9.4 gems.

When Ruby opens the site I am testing. Before the page loads an Authentication Required pop up box is displayed. It says, "The server http://example.com:80 requires a username and password. The server says: Authentication Required." I am not able to inspect it as an element, therefore I don't know how to interact with it. I have been bypassing the issue by manually entering the username and password.

I think it will be easier to just fill the fields in and click Log In rather then store a cookie, but you guys will know best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass in the authentication credentials via the URL, which will bypass the dialog.  There's an example on http://watirwebdriver.com/basic-browser-authentication/:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
b = Watir::Browser.start 'http://admin:password@yourwebsite.com'
b.goto 'https://admin:password@yourwebsite.com/cart'  # replace 'cart' as appropriate
```

Comment: I am working on a eCommerce site that is not live yet, and when I click to checkout, then the authentication box displays again. Any ideas on how to deal with this?

Comment: Since you're going to checkout, you're probably going from `http` to `https`.    I've edited with a hacky workaround that basically primes the pump when you launch the browser.